# Batch delete exif info

Tags: linux, bash, image-manipulation, exif

How can I recursively remove the EXIF info from several thousand JPG files?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The other ExifTool suggestions are great if you want to remove or change specific sections. But if you want to just remove all of the metadata completely, use this (from the man page):

```
   exiftool -all= dst.jpg
        Delete all meta information from an image.
```

You could also use [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/), with the -de flag:

```
   -de    Delete the Exif header entirely.  Leaves  other  metadata
          sections intact.
```

Note that in both cases, EXIF is only one type of metadata. Other metadata sections may be present, and depending on what you want to do, both of these programs have different options for preserving some or removing it all. For example, `jhead -purejpg` strips all information not needed for rendering the image.

Answer (score 11):

The EXIF handling tool [`exiv2`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/exiv2.1.html) has a command for deleting EXIF data:

```
exiv2 rm image.jpg
```

removes all EXIF data from the image.

To remove EXIF data from all JPEG images in the current directory, use

```
exiv2 rm *.jpg
```

To remove EXIF data from all JPEG images in the current directory, and all subdirectories of it recursively, use:

**`find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' | xargs exiv2 rm`**

It is a good idea to test the command before.

To see which files are found:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' | less
```

To see which commands will be executed:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' | xargs echo exiv2 rm | less
```

Note the `echo` inserted before `exiv2` to print the command, instead of running it.

Answer (score 4):

You should look at some opensource tools like [exiftool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). There is a lot of option (for exif, xmp, iptc).

```
exiftool -overwrite_original \
-xmp:Creator='votre nom' \
-xmp:WebStatement='http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/' \
-xmp:Rights='Copyright votre nom. This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-No Derivative Works 3.0  License.' \
-iptc:By-line='votre nom' \
-iptc:CopyrightNotice='Copyright votre nom. This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-No Derivative Works 3.0  License.' \
-exif:Artist='votre nom' \
-exif:Copyright='Copyright votre nom. This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-No Derivative Works 3.0  License.' \
votre_fichier.jpg
```

The only thing you should do next is to write a tiny script that lists your files (jpg) and does the stuff. To remove the content of a field you'll have to set it to " ^" ; like the following example:

```
-Software= ^
-ModifyDate= ^
-CreatorTool= ^
-MetadataDate= ^
-Rating= ^
-ImageNumber= ^
-WhiteBalance= ^
-Temperature= ^
-Tint= ^
-IncrementalTemperature= ^
-IncrementalTint= ^
-Exposure= ^
-Shadows= ^
-Brightness= ^
-Contrast= ^
-Saturation= ^
-Sharpness= ^
-LuminanceSmoothing= ^
-ColorNoiseReduction= ^
-ChromaticAberrationR= ^
-ChromaticAberrationB= ^
-VignetteAmount= ^
-VignetteMidpoint= ^
-ShadowTint= ^
-RedHue= ^
-RedSaturation= ^-GreenHue= ^
-GreenSaturation= ^
-BlueHue= ^
-BlueSaturation= ^
-FillLight= ^
-Vibrance= ^
-HighlightRecovery= ^
-Clarity= ^
-Defringe= ^
-HueAdjustmentRed= ^
-HueAdjustmentOrange= ^
-HueAdjustmentYellow= ^
-HueAdjustmentGreen= ^
-HueAdjustmentAqua= ^
-HueAdjustmentBlue= ^
-HueAdjustmentPurple= ^
-HueAdjustmentMagenta= ^
-SaturationAdjustmentRed= ^
-SaturationAdjustmentOrange= ^
-SaturationAdjustmentYellow= ^
-SaturationAdjustmentGreen= ^
-SaturationAdjustmentAqua= ^
-SaturationAdjustmentBlue= ^
-SaturationAdjustmentPurple= ^
-SaturationAdjustmentMagenta= ^
-LuminanceAdjustmentRed= ^
-LuminanceAdjustmentOrange= ^
-LuminanceAdjustmentYellow= ^
-LuminanceAdjustmentGreen= ^
-LuminanceAdjustmentAqua= ^
-LuminanceAdjustmentBlue= ^
-LuminanceAdjustmentPurple= ^
-LuminanceAdjustmentMagenta= ^
-SplitToningShadowHue= ^
-SplitToningShadowSaturation= ^
-SplitToningHighlightHue= ^
-SplitToningHighlightSaturation= ^
-SplitToningBalance= ^
-ParametricShadows= ^
-ParametricDarks= ^
-ParametricLights= ^
-ParametricHighlights= ^
-ParametricShadowSplit= ^
-ParametricMidtoneSplit= ^
-ParametricHighlightSplit= ^
-SharpenRadius= ^
-SharpenDetail= ^
-SharpenEdgeMasking= ^
-ConvertToGrayscale= ^
-ToneCurveName= ^
-CameraProfile= ^
-HasSettings= ^
-CropTop= ^
-CropLeft= ^
-CropBottom= ^
-CropRight= ^
-CropAngle= ^
-CropWidth= ^
-CropHeight= ^
-CropUnit= ^
-HasCrop= ^
-AlreadyApplied= ^
-ToneCurve= ^
-CameraProfile= ^
-ApplicationRecordVersion= ^
```

Answer (score 3):

Vincent's [suggestion of using exiftool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13251/batch-delete-exif-info/13252#13252) is good. I suggest you write a script that accepts a single argument of a filename, and runs your desired strip functions on that. Then use `find` to execute this script on your file set. The script would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exiftool -overwrite_original -ExifFieldName=^ [-MoreExifFieldNames=^] $1
```

Say you save this as `/usr/local/bin/strip_exif.sh`, you could then call it by going to the folder that has your jpeg files like this:

```
find -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec strip_exif.sh {} \;
```

**Edit:** After seeing [mattdm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13251/batch-delete-exif-info/13264#13264) about the argument for striping all tags, I figure you can skip the script and just use the find like this:

```
find -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec exiftool -all= {} \;
```