# Removing all tags from images

Tags: image-manipulation, jpeg, exif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Batch delete exif info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13251/batch-delete-exif-info)

How can I remove all tags from images under a directory (using Linux)? I can find all files with something like `find pictures -type f -iname "*jpg" -exec FOO "{}" \;` but what should `FOO` be?

Comment: `exiftool -all=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exiv2 rm` it is available in many platform.

[Exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org/) is a C++ library and a command line utility to manage image metadata.